# use of char * vs std::string in different environments

Tags: c++

I have been using std::string in my code. I was going to make a std::string and pass it by reference. However, someone suggested using a char * instead. Something about std::string is not reliable when porting code. Is that true? I have avoided using char * as I would need to do some memory management for it. Instead I find using the std::string much easier to use.

Basically I have a 10 digit output that I am storing in this string. Atm, I am not sure which would be better to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, almost every string should be std::string unless another library requires a cstring, in which case you should still be using an std::string and passing string.c_str(), unless you're using functions that work with buffers.

However, if you're writing a library and exporting functions, it's better to use const char* parameters rather than std::string parameters for portability.

Comment: for portability? in the aforementioned discussion people seem to suggest that w/e issues would plague char * would also be the same for std::string. i am not sure i get that. Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by using buffers? The reason I ask that is because although I am writing this code on unix that will have a console interface. the windows version of this will be a dll and will most likely have api that will be called by third party programs.

Comment: const char* will be the exact same no matter who/what is using your code. std::string may not, especially if you're statically linked with the C++ runtime. If I compile and export a function void foo(const std::string) into a static library using C++ runtime 2.0, then compile and ship it to a client who uses C++ runtime 1.8, which doesn't use the same string implementation, things will blow up because their std::string isn't what my program expects when it wants an std::string

Comment: so basically i have to modify my code to remove all instances of the std::string and change it to char *. this is what I am understanding in order to not have any issues.

Comment: You don't have to, it's just more portable to make exported functions take const char*; if they aren't exported, they can take std::string without any problems. Either way, I construct an std::string with a char* after it's been passed, since C++ code should always use std::string where possible.

Answer (score 12):

std::string is part of the C++ Standard, and has been since 1998. It is available in all the current C++ compilers. There really is no portability reason not to use it. If you have an API that needs to use a C-style string, you can use the std::string's `c_str()` member to get one from a string:

```
std::string s = "foo";
int n = strlen( s.c_str() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `char *` you are sure that you will not get portability issues among libraries.
If a library exports a function that uses an `std::string`, it might have problems communicating with another library that has been linked against a different version of the standard library.

Comment: You will have similar possible problems with char * if the thing being allocated to the char * is deallocated in a different library.

Comment: @Neil: Well, that's a different kind of problem. Please note that I'm not encouraging the use of char* per se, I'm just saying that this could be a possible source of problems with std::strings, since the question is "someone suggested that... is it true?"

Comment: @Neil: that's true, but many APIs don't pass ownership of memory around - if all you do is read and write within the limits of my char* buffer, I don't care how you allocate memory. Whereas any use of a `std::string` can go wrong if the libraries aren't compatible. So, while it's possible to go wrong when using `char*`, there are many things you can do. With std::string, you simply can't call across the library incompatibility boundary at all. So whether char* is any better depends whether "I would need to do some memory management" in the question means, "across the boundary", or not.

Comment: I am currently working on this code in unix which has a console interface. however i will be providing a static library (dll) for win environment. In that case should i be working with char * arrays instead? I don't want to do extra work for the windows platform anymore than is necessary. which means that if i know i will have to remove the console functionality. however, other than providing apis i want my code to be seemeless....which from what you guys are saying seems like i would need  to stick with char * instead of std::strings.

Comment: @unknown Your original question was about portability, but it seems you should have been asking about library API design. The two issues are somewhat related, but by no means the same. It may be a good idea to ask a new question (don't edit this one) explaining exactly what you want to do, and not using words like "porting" if you are not sure of their meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is nothing to worry about unless you are going to provide some API to 3rd party.

Just use `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing unportable about `std::string` that isn't also an issue with `char *`. `std::string` actually uses a `char *` internally...

Answer (score 0):

string is better. There is nothing unreliable about it on any platform. If you're worried about passing large classes, you can pass const references of your strings into functions. Makes coding faster and less bug prone.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fact thata it's easier, `std::string` will probably be more efficient. Its small string optimization can keep the 10 digits in the `std::string` object itself, instead of putting them in another memory block off the heap.